# Determining the mass of my car via m = F/a

Tags: forces, mass, momentum, acceleration, torque

I'd like to do something unconventional. I'd like to weigh my car by hitting the gas. I have an accelerometer in my phone (a). I'm trying to determine the force the car is exerting (against the road, I presume?). Also through my phone I have access to near-instantaneous horsepower, torque, and RPMs via the data port. I believe the phone just multiplies the RPMs by the torque/hp curves to get those numbers.

If P = W/t, and P = Fv, and F = ma, then I should be able to just rearrange these equations to get Force, right? Am I on a fool's errand? Also I think I can use torque but that seems slightly more confusing.

Assuming converting hp to W, also assuming some trivial conversion factors for determining force at wheels vs. force at engine.

(Edit: correction from comments)

Comment: Note that $P=Fv$. In principle you can find $F$ and $a$ and then obtain $m$. However I do not think the reading you have for power would be accurate. I guess a good fraction of car power is spent in thermal energy.

Comment: In my opinion, you can get a reasonable estimate for hp from the hp curve of your engine.  If you can establish that the hp curve was derived from actual measurements on a dynamometer, you will know that the data correspond to hp delivered to the rear wheels.  If, on the other hand, the hp was calculated for the engine only, the power losses in the drive train will be unknown, and your method will produce a number that is too large.